# Can you identify if this part is original?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, clone-brands

Recently, I bought a LEGO part from Bricklink ([Technic, Steering Arm with 4 Ball Joints with Black Wheel Hub (x872 / x873)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=10763&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)).

I'm not sure if it is an original part or not, because I don't see any LEGO trademark or ID number on the element and I cannot find any reference for that part. The only text on the brick is a single digit (e.g. "7").

Quality of the item is really good, so I believe it's original, but I need to be sure.

[image]

[image: digit is marked in red]

[image]

Comment: I've added the Clone-Brands tag off of the OP's suspicion of "doppelgangery", not that this piece has been proven to be cloned or not.

Answer (score 3):

I got such pieces from sealed set (long time ago though) and none of these parts have any sort of LEGO brand identification.

So it could be legit part after all.